# Are PIE *bal and *welH- related?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

Has anyone compared eg. *Bhumibol* - title of Thailand's monarch, derived from Sanskrit - and *oblast* - a Slavic noun related to rule and governance, vb. *voldati "to rule, to reign, to govern"?

Comment: Isn't that a stretch?

Comment: which is why i have no idea and am hoping for priors'

Comment: I might have misremembered the title. I only know that the Sanskrit word turned up when I looked into the royal name (https://youtu.be/F2TTPCXoZWA 00:12). It goes without saying that PIEness of like  *\*bal* is quite a stretch anyway.

Comment: The PIE root is *\*bel-*. PIE *\*e* and *\*o* both turned into *a* in Sanskrit. There's obviously no good reason to believe it's related to *\*h₂welh₁-*; there is no visible alternation between *\*w* and *\*b* in PIE anywhere else, and if the *\*b-* in *\*bel-* came from anywhere it was more likely *\*m* (cf. Latin *melior* / Greek βελτίων, also Latin *mālum* / English *apple* for a different root with *\*b*), though that's tentative.

Comment: @Cairnarvon ahah, the *it's obvious* defense. Why didn't I think of that!?

Answer (score 1):

The name is a compound of Sanskrit bhūmi- “land” and (I assume) bala- “strength”. The latter is (as has been mentioned) cognate to Greel βελτίων,  “better”, so with IE *b not *w-.